# How to get rest of props from React-Table to custom plugin Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-table-v7

How can we get  props that we are passing to React-Table component (just like we passed options object like data and columns ) and  table instance gives us both columns and data in instance object . So how can we get extra props that we passed along with data and columns to any custom plugin Hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass that props along with columns, data to useTable primary Hook.

UseTable({columns, data , props1 , props2}) and we can get it in instance object .